# PROBLEMAS CON FECHA EN PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, date

quisiera que me apoyen resulta que tengo un valor fecha en mi base de datos que guarda un valor datetime, pero al querer mostrar en mi web necesito decirle con una condicional cuando este formato sea 0000-00-00 00:00:00 me muestre con un echo 'vacio o sin fecha' y cuando este campo tenga un valor '2022-01-10 15:56:22' simplemente me muestre ese valor. He intentado pero no me sale el resultado. Agradecere si alguien me puede apoyar ya que recien empiezo en el mundo del php. Gracias

Comment: Hola! Recuerda que las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para refrescar ideas sobre el sitio. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supongo que quieres algo así, suponiendo que la variable se llame `$fecha`, y debes hacerlo antes de mostrarla en la web:

```
if ($fecha == '0000-00-00 00:00:00') {
  $fecha = '';
}
```

Y con esto cambias el valor de la variable y cuando la muestres no saldrá nada (o lo que pongas dentro de los apóstrofes).

Comment: Muchas gracias lo implementare y lo comentare

Comment: no te olvides @DanielPacheco de marcar el check si te sirvió la respuestas de este maquina, es muy bueno en php y me ayudo mucho.

Comment: muchas gracias amigo me sirvio mucho tu ayuda le puse ese codigo y me salio correcto.